# K8s: gets HTTP 415 for PATCH request to Kubernetes REST API server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-apiserver

I have seen that PATCH request is supported in Kubernetes REST API reference manual from this link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#patch-ingress-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io

```
HTTP Request
PATCH /apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/ingresses/{name}
```

However, I get HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type error when sending PATCH request to Kubernetes cluster through Kubernetes REST API server in Postman.

I want to update our specified ingress partially outside the cluster. For this purpose, I added a snapshot from my trial.

[Kubernetes REST API server Ingress PATCH Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK1kR.png)

Our Kubernetes version is:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Patching JSON:

```
{
   "apiVersion": "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1",
   "kind": "Ingress",
   "metadata": {
      "name": "demo-ingress",
      "annotations": {
         "nginx.org/rewrites": "serviceName=demo-service-235 rewrite=/"
      }
   },
   "spec": {
      "rules": [
         {
            "host": "www.demodeployment.com",
            "http": {
               "paths": [
                  {
                     "path": "/235/",
                     "backend": {
                        "serviceName": "demo-service-235",
                        "servicePort": 8088
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I can use GET, POST, PUT and DELETE successfully, in PATCH request I can't get the same results. What could be the root cause of the problem? What are your ideas?

Comment: could you share what kind of data you are patching? if possible share json file whihc you are patching?

Comment: I will, but I think that it is not related to patching because whatever I write, I always get the same error.

Comment: Fwiw, I'm also encountering this on 1.18

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this same issue by setting the following header:

```
"Content-Type": "application/strategic-merge-patch+json"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I don't want to rewrite ingress for each time. I want to add a new ingress onto the old one without deleting and rewriting.

Answer (score 4):

Set `Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json` in the header.

Also I would suggest to first try to patch using  `kubectl patch --v=8` with increased verbosity which will display the http request and payload being sent by kubectl to Kubernetes API Server. Then you can take the same request payload and use from postman.

Comment: I did it and I take HTTP 405 "The server does not allow this method on the requested resource" error, reason "MethodNotAllowed". However, I can use GET, POST, PUT and DELETE successfully.

Comment: 405 error on every request or only on patching ingress? can you try patching image in pod or deployment?

Comment: I am only patching on ingress for this case and I tried what you said such as deployment now. I take the same error like HTTP 405 "The server does not allow this method on the requested resource" error, reason "MethodNotAllowed"

Comment: try `kubectl patch` with verbosity increased as updated in answer

Comment: Yes, it is ok from here. However, I want to use it outside the cluster. I think that it needs permission to reach to the cluster for PATCH request. How can I get permission for it?

Comment: you need to send a token in the header of http request...for token you can create a service account and then role and rolebinding to give permission to that service account

Comment: Token added already. I can use GET, POST, PUT and DELETE successfully. However, I cannot do with PATCH request.

Comment: if it's a permission issue you should get 403 error code

Comment: Hımm ok, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Did you try from kubectl to check the request and payload ? Are you using the same token from kubeconfig in the postman ?

Comment: I got like that: ingress.extensions/demo-ingress-d-5f9c151f patched (no change)